# Content uri becomes inaccessible after time

Tags: android, gallery, android-videoview

I have a strange behavior in my android app. During the runtime app takes some files from users phone gallery throught contnet uri. If i do operations on that uri right after it comes from gallery intent all works as expected, content uri is avaliable and i can set it to video_view:

```
Observable.timer(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            {
                setVideo(content_uri)
            })
```

But exactly same code with delay of 500 millisecods gives me :

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FVID_20190923_231409.mp4: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{72d519b 7242:com.babydayka/u0a402} (pid=7242, uid=10402) that is not exported from uid 10032
```

How can i solve this strange behavior if i need to use content uri some time after it picked?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Hi, I think your problem because the permission time limit. Can't use permission for URI for a long time.